# Referring to Initialize variables in an Angular Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a factory that is responsible for generating a PlayerList, but I'm having problems accessing the variables I set in the initialize function. The code is

```
app.factory("PlayerList", function(){

    // Define the PlayerList function
    var PlayerList = function() {

        this.initialize = function() {
            // create an array for our players
            var players = [];
        };

        this.add = function(player) {
            this.players.push(player);
        }

        this.remove = function(player) {
            if ( players.length > 0 )
            {
                this.players.splice(players.indexOf(player), 1);    
            }
        }

        this.initialize();
    };

    return (PlayerList);

});
```

I want to refer to the players array inside the add and remove methods but I'm getting back undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `var players = [];` is local variable for `initialize` but your are expecting `this.players.push(player);` means `players` should be in `PlayerList` scope.

So your factory should be look like

```
app.factory("PlayerList", function () {

    // Define the PlayerList function
    var PlayerList = function () {

        var self = this;

        this.players = [];

        this.initialize = function () {
            self.players = [];
        };

        this.add = function (player) {
            self.players.push(player);
            console.log(self.players);
        }

        this.remove = function (player) {
            if (self.players.length > 0) {
                self.players.splice(self.players.indexOf(player), 1);
            }
        }

        this.initialize();
    };

    return (PlayerList);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

var playerList = (function (){

var playerLists = {};

playerList.playerList = function() {

```
    this.initialize = function() {
        // create an array for our players
        var players = [];
    };

    this.add = function(player) {
        this.players.push(player);
    }

    this.remove = function(player) {
        if ( players.length > 0 )
        {
            this.players.splice(players.indexOf(player), 1);    
        }
    }

    this.initialize();
};

return playerLists;
```

})();

app.factory("PlayerList",playerList.playerList);